# How can I prevent mesh clipping?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to bend this mesh from every corner upwards slightly using the lattice modifier. I'm thinking I should try a different tool as this one has the mesh "clipping" or going through each other, even though they're one layer. Any ideas?[image]

Comment: Please consider an armature. Bones. Mesh Modifier is available. Or Bend the for tubes that meet in the middle ... sooner.

Comment: Add additional geometry on the faces of the roof (not the tiles) If there are not enough edges for the faces to bend, it will have to protrude like this. Please post a screnshot in wireframe mode :)